# How to perform ADF test in C# using R.Net

Tags: c#, r, r.net

I am trying to make R (and its extensive analytical capabilities) usable in my C# projects.

The ultimate bridge between R library and the C# environment is R.net.

I finalized the set up of R.Net and began writing my first application that basically

1. performs a simple test (using R engine)
2. and presents the test result on the console.
3. that is it.

the following is the code that I was able to draft so far, which returns error!

So, how can I debug my code so that the R.Net performs the ADF test?

Thanks in advance for your time and help!

Best,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using RDotNet;
using System.IO;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        // set the environment for RDotNet dll
        var envPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH");
        var rBinPath = @"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.1\bin\i386";
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", envPath + Path.PathSeparator + rBinPath);

        // create one instance of RDotNet dll
        REngine engine = REngine.CreateInstance("RDotNet");
        engine.Initialize();

        // some test data - alternative 1- from .NET array to R vector.
        NumericVector group1 = engine.CreateNumericVector(new double[] { 30.02, 29.99, 30.11, 29.97, 30.01, 29.99 });
        engine.SetSymbol("group1", group1);

        // some test data - alternative 2 - from direct coding to R vector.
        NumericVector group2 = engine.Evaluate("group2 <- c(29.89, 29.93, 29.72, 29.98, 30.02, 29.98)").AsNumeric();

        #region: t-test as an example
        string testCommand = "t.test(group1, group2)";
        GenericVector tTest = engine.Evaluate(testCommand).AsList();
        double p = tTest["p.value"].AsNumeric().First();

        // present the results on console
        Console.WriteLine("Group1: [{0}]", string.Join(", ", group1));
        Console.WriteLine("Group2: [{0}]", string.Join(", ", group2));
        Console.WriteLine("P-value = {0:0.000}", p);

        // THIS WORKED WELL!! OK!! NO ISSUES SO FAR!!
        #endregion

        #region: adf test as another example

        // write the command
        testCommand = @"adf.test(group1,alternative=""stationary"")";
        Console.WriteLine("testCommand: " + testCommand);

        // get the result
        engine.Evaluate(testCommand);
        GenericVector adfTest = engine.Evaluate(testCommand).AsList();
        // THIS RETURNS ERROR!! ERROR MESSAGE IS NOT CLEAR TO UNDERSTAND AND RESOLVE!

        #endregion.

        // you should always dispose of the REngine properly.
        // After disposing of the engine, you cannot reinitialize nor reuse it
        engine.Dispose();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic reason for the adf not working is that, the required libraries to perform the adf test should be made available (i.e. loaded and/or attached via the library() method of R)

After the libraries are loaded, the only problem for this code not running would simply be typos and other syntax errors.

I revised the code, and it is now working properly.

the revised code is as follows (a simplified version):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using RDotNet;
using System.IO;

using commonTools;

namespace RDesk
{
    class Program
    {




        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            // set the environment for RDotNet dll
            var envPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH");
            var rBinPath = @"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.1\bin\i386";
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", envPath + Path.PathSeparator + rBinPath);

            // create one instance of RDotNet dll
            REngine engine = REngine.CreateInstance("RDotNet");
            engine.Initialize();

            // some test data - alternative 1- from .NET array to R vector.
            NumericVector group1 = engine.CreateNumericVector(new double[] { 30.02, 29.99, 30.11, 29.97, 30.01, 29.99 });
            engine.SetSymbol("group1", group1);

            // some test data - alternative 2 - from direct coding to R vector.
            NumericVector group2 = engine.Evaluate("group2 <- c(29.89, 29.93, 29.72, 29.98, 30.02, 29.98)").AsNumeric();

            #region: t-test as an example
            string testCommand = "t.test(group1, group2)";
            GenericVector tTest = engine.Evaluate(testCommand).AsList();
            double p = tTest["p.value"].AsNumeric().First();

            // present the results on console
            Console.WriteLine("Group1: [{0}]", string.Join(", ", group1));
            Console.WriteLine("Group2: [{0}]", string.Join(", ", group2));
            Console.WriteLine("P-value = {0:0.000}", p);
            #endregion


            #region: adf test as another example


            string adfTestCommand
            = " library(tseries) " + System.Environment.NewLine
            + " library(forecast) " + System.Environment.NewLine
            + "adfTest = " + @"adf.test(group1,alternative=""stationary"", k=0)" 
            + System.Environment.NewLine// df test
            ;

            // get the result
            // engine.Evaluate(RCommand);
            GenericVector adfTest = engine.Evaluate(RCommand).AsList();

            #endregion.




            // you should always dispose of the REngine properly.
            // After disposing of the engine, you cannot reinitialize nor reuse it
            engine.Dispose();

        }
    }
}
```